# Is it possible to fix Gateway timeout for REST API Java

Tags: java, timeout, quarkus

I have a rest API

```
public Response createBulk(File xlsx){
  doSmth();
  return Response.status(Status.ACCEPTED).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

And I have timeout from response when upload a huge file. And, by the way, I have no issues from logs about it and **every time timeout ~ 30s**. I use **quarkus** and want to increase timeout value, from 30s to 120s as example. Is it possible to do? Because I tried to find this info here https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#duration-note-anchor-quarkus-all-config and I couldn't do this, because there wasn't default timeout value = 30s.

Comment: Are you sure that the timeout is on the server side and not on the client side? Red Hat uses 30 seconds for the test client (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_build_of_quarkus/1.11/html/testing_your_quarkus_applications/proc-setting-the-timeout-period-for-http-test-connections_quarkus-testing) and that can be changed, but in real life you have another client. Perhaps it uses the same timeout value?

Comment: You might be right, but I checked every client server and didn't find anything with this default value, so I assumed it could be from server...but what is strange for me - I have no issues from the server logs. By the way, I tested it manually via postman, so I had this: me (postman) -> server -> db (pg)

Comment: Do you have something in front of quarkus (a load balancer or web front) or is it a direct call? Do you get a HTTP timeout (without response) or do you get a HTTP response that complains about a gateway timeout? If it is a HTTP timeout then it should be on the client side as it is the client that controls that. If on the other hand it is a response with an error code it should be on the server.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of operations usually are resolved using a message: in `createBulk()` just send a notification and somewhere in your system perform bulk operation.
Using [eventBus](https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-event-bus) can be a viable solution.

```
public Response createBulk(File xlsx) {
  eventBus.sendAndForget(BULK_IMPORT, xlsx);
  return Response.status(Status.ACCEPTED).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class BulkOperationService {
    @ConsumeEvent(BULK_IMPORT)
    public void bulkImport(File file) {
      // perform bulk operation
    }
}
```